# dnsmasq to route a subdomain

Tags: linux, dnsmasq

I've setup OpenMediaVault with NextClound on a RPi4. To access it I setup a domain on duckdns, mydomain.duckdns.org. Nginx is configured to use a subdomain to access nextcloud, so from outside of my network I can open nextcloud using nextcloud.mydomain.duckdns.org, however I can't access it locally because my router doesn't support NAT loopback.

After some research I found out that I can use dnsmasq to route nextcloud.mydomain.duckdns.org locally. I followed some guides with no success.

Below is my dnsmasq config file and now If I `dig nextcloud.mydomain.duckdns.org` it gets the local IP, but using it on a browser gets ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

```
# Never forward plain names (without a domain) domain-needed
# Turn off DHCP on eth0
no-dhcp-interface=eth0
# Never forward addresses in the non-routable address space (RFC1918)
bogus-priv
# Add domain to host names
#expand-hosts
# Domain to be added if expand-hosts is set
domain=mydomain.duckdns.org
# Local domain to be served from /etc/hosts file
#local=/zola.home/
# Don't read /etc/resolv.conf (I deleted it). Get the external name server from this file, see 'server' below
no-resolv
no-poll
# External server, works with no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8

address=/mydomain.duckdns.org/192.168.1.108
```

Any idea on how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Guess: DNS resolution works, but something else doesn't work, so what you need to debug is not `dnsmasq`. What happens if you do e.g. `curl https://nextcloud.mydomain.duckdns.org` (or `http`, depending on what you use)?

Comment: ```ze-mac-2:~ ze$ curl https://nextcloud.mydomain.duckdns.org
curl: (7) Failed to connect to nextcloud.mydomain.duckdns.org port 443: Connection refused```
Will check if nginx is blocking local connections somehow

Comment: "Connection refused" can also mean something in between is blocking it, e.g. because you have not allowed port 443.